# Activeform Yii2 ajax validation не отображаются error сообщения

Tags: ajax, yii2, валидация, activeform

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'default',
    'options' => ['class' => 'welcome__modal-form'],

    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{input}",
        'options' => [
            'tag' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
<div class="modal-row">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Войти') ?>
    <a class="forget__card" href="#">Забыл номер карты/кодовое слово</a>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end();
```

контроллер:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
```

модель:

```
class LoginForm extends Model
{
public $username;
public $password;
public $rememberMe = true;

private $_user = false;


/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // username and password are both required
        [['username', 'password'], 'required', 'message' => 'Please choose a username.'],
        // password is validated by validatePassword()
        ['password', 'validatePassword'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Validates the password.
 * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
 *
 * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
 * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
 */
  public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
 {
    $user = User::findByUsername($this->username);

    if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
        $this->addError('password', 'Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль.');
    }

}
```

такое ощущение что именно в форме не выводит. В чем проблема кода моего?

Comment: у вас в template только `{input}`, ошибку то куда выводить? вот стандартный template `"{label}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"`

Comment: {error} добавлял не помогло

Comment: `'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{input}\n{error}",
        'options' => [
            'tag' => false,
        ],
    ], ` вот так сделал. ничего не поменялось. добавился `<p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>` в верстке. но туда ничего не выводится

Comment: а `yii\web\YiiAsset` подключён?

Comment: `use yii\web\YiiAsset; ` добавил во вьюшку. ничего не изменилось

Comment: YiiAsset::register($this);

Comment: `use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\web\YiiAsset;

YiiAsset::register($this);` ничего не изменилось

Comment: при этом есть страница login стандартная с формой отдельная. Там все работает. а в попапе нет

Comment: в каком попапе?

Answer (score 1):

В добавление к вышеперечисленным проблемам надо указывать идентификатор формы.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
'layout' => 'default',
'id' => 'login-form',
...
```

Естественно не забудьте темплейт

```
'template' => '{input}\n{error}'
```

Comment: добавил id в форму http://prntscr.com/jrnx5t но эррор ни в какую не хочет

Comment: А что возвращает сервер при валидации?

Comment: а как вытянуть ответ сервера?

Comment: в хроме жмем ctrl+j потом обновляем страницу и смотрим вкладку Network. Там применяем фильтр и оставляем только XHR запросы. Жмем отправить форму и смотрим что прилетело.

Comment: {"loginform-password":["Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль."]}